# Bounded subspaces of a normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Which vector subspaces of a normed linear space are bounded subsets?

My approach :=

$A\subseteq X$ ($X$ is a normed linear space ) is bounded iff there exists an $M>0$ such that $||x|| \leq M$ for all $x \in A$

1. Clearly the trivial subspace is bounded.

Now I am unable to think further...

Comment: Hint: You found the only one there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a normed linear space (over $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$) and $A \subseteq X$ is a subspace of $X$ containing some non-zero $\mathbf{x}$, then $A$ contains the unbounded subset $\{ n \mathbf{x} : n \in \mathbf{N} \}$. It follows that the trivial subspace is the only bounded subspace of $X$.